# How to evaluate $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-|x|}}{|1-\sin x|^{\frac{1}{4}}} \,dx$?

Tags: analysis

$$\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-|x|}}{|1-\sin x|^{\frac{1}{4}}} \,dx$$

Any advice and comments will be appreciated

Comment: It might be worth noting that the range for $\sin x$ is $-1\leq \sin x \leq 1$. Therefore $|1−\sin x|$ is always positive and so you can remove the absolute value in the denominator.

Comment: This is the integral on $(0,2\pi)$ of the same function without the absolute values, times $2/(1-\mathrm e^{-2\pi})$.

Comment: To see what Didier Piau means you might divide the interval into intervals of length $2\pi$ and use periodicity of the denominator together with the fact that $\exp(-x-2n\pi)= \exp(-2n\pi)\exp(-x)$ (giving a geometrical series).

Comment: @DidierPiau I see what you mean, but not if it helps..

Comment: Is this homework? For what class? Are you supposed to know complex analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my thoughts so far -- not an answer, just a possible start.

Observing that $\sin x\le1$,
we can easily remove the absolute values:
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{e^{-|x|}}{|1-\sin x|^{\frac{1}{4}}}
\,dx
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{e^{-x}}{(1-\sin x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}
\,dx.
$$
A major challenge of solving this integral with a substitution
is that the denominator is periodic, with poles at $x=(2n+\frac12)\pi$.
For example, with $z=\tan\frac{x}{2}$, we'd have
$dz=\frac12\sec^2\frac{x}{2}dx$ $=$ $\frac12(1+z^2)dx$
or $dx=\frac{2}{1+z^2}dz$
and $x=\frac{2z}{1+z^2}$ which would yield
$$
I=2\int_{0}^{?}
\frac{e^{-2\tan^{-1}z}}{(1-\sin x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}
\,dx,
$$
but there would be no way to transform the upper limits integration!
However, this problem can be surmounted by integrating separately
over each period of $\sin x$ to obtain
$$
\eqalign{
I
&=
2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi(n+1)}
\frac{e^{-x}}{(1-\sin x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}
\,dx \cr
&=
2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
e^{-2n\pi}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\frac{e^{-x}}{(1-\sin x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}
\,dx \cr
&=
\frac2{1-e^{-2\pi}}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\frac{e^{-x}}{(1-\sin x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}
\,dx.
}
$$
This is an improper integral, but it exists because
$1-\sin x$ as $x$ approaches $\frac\pi 2$ behaves the same way that
$1-\cos x$ does as $x$ approaches $0$, namely like $x^2$, and
$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^p}$ exists for $0<p<1.$

At this point we have at least a few options to pursue. We could:

- use a Taylor series expansion for
  $(1-\sin x)^{-\frac14}=\sum a_nx^n$
  and integrate each term $\sum a_nx^ne^{-x}$
- carry out a substitution like the one above,
  or like $x=t^2$ to get
  $$
  I=\frac2{1-e^{-2\pi}}
  \int_0^\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{2te^{-t^2}dt}{(1-\sin t^2)^{\frac14}}
  %\quad\text{or}\quad
  %I=2\int_0^\infty\frac{2te^{-t^2}dt}{(1-\sin t^2)^{\frac14}}
  $$
- use
  $\int e^{-x}(1+\sin x)^{\frac14}(\cosh ix)^{-\frac12}\,dx$
  and possibly end up integrating in the complex plane.

There is presumably a way since sage reports $3.2916690469253642$,
but I haven't checked how it's getting that.

Comment: This is what Mathematica gives for the integral that you got stuck $$-\left(\frac{4}{25}-\frac{28 i}{25}\right) \left(\,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4}+i,1;\frac{1}{4}+i;-i\right)-(1+i) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4}+i,1;\frac{1}{4}+i;-i\right)\right)+\left(\frac{4}{25}-\frac
   {28 i}{25}\right) e^{-2 \pi } \left(\,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4}+i,1;\frac{1}{4}+i;-i\right)-(1+i) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4}+i,1;\frac{1}{4}+i;-i\right)\right)+\frac{2^{3/4} e^{-\pi
   /2} \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}+i\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{4}+i\right)}$$

Comment: I noticed that (1) the Taylor series for $(\frac{1-\cos x}{2})^{-\frac14}/\sqrt x$ converges very nicely and (2) that $x=t^2$ might take the integral slightly closer in your direction. What is $F_1$?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html

Comment: Looks like Barnes integral: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Barnes_integral.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to simplify the result $$\frac{1}{425 \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}+i\right)}\Biggl(e^{-2 \pi } \left((176+432 i) \left(e^{2 \pi }-1\right) \left(-1+\,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4}+i,1;\frac{1}{4}+i;-i\right)\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{7}{4}+i\right)+425\ 2^{3/4} e^{3 \pi /2} \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{4}+i\right)\right)\Biggr)$$

Comment: The integrand is not an even function. I've confirmed in Wolframalpha but I am not able to type here the correct link.